# New Domain got marked as spam after 3 mailer in Gmail

Tags: spam, spam-prevention, gmail

We just started with our mailing activity, and for our warm up, we send the first mail to 1000 emails. On second day we took a big jump and went over to 5000, then 9000 and now at 12000.

Unfortunately right after the first mail, gmail marked us as spam.

isNOTspam breakup is listed below. Not sure why it says DKIM failing. Any other reasons why we got marked as spam?

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================

SPF Check : pass
Sender-ID Check : pass
DKIM Check : invalid
SpamAssassin Check : ham (non-spam)
==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname: a8-16.smtp-out.amazonses.com
Source IP: 54.240.8.16
mail-from: newsletter@marketing.rupyacard.com
Anonymous To: ins-1o0neojk@isnotspam.com
---------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=newsletter@marketing.rupyacard.com
DNS record(s):
rupyacard.com.  3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:zoho.com include:amazonses.com ~all"


----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass

ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=newsletter@marketing.rupyacard.com
DNS record(s):
rupyacard.com.  3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:zoho.com include:amazonses.com ~all"


----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: invalid
ID(s) verified: header.From=newsletter@marketing.rupyacard.com
Selector=2v7oaw3uek2ggiio5bsiibhbwimyo5tw
domain=marketing.rupyacard.com
DomainKeys DNS Record=2v7oaw3uek2ggiio5bsiibhbwimyo5tw._domainkey.marketing.rupyacard.com

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=newsletter@marketing.rupyacard.com
Selector=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono
domain=amazonses.com
DomainKeys DNS Record=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono._domainkey.amazonses.com

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28)

Result: ham (non-spam) (01.0points, 10.0 required)

pts rule name description
---- ---------------------- -------------------------------


* -0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, no
* trust
* [54.240.8.16 listed in list.dnswl.org]
* 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -2.8 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2 RBL: Average reputation (+2)
* [54.240.8.16 listed in wl.mailspike.net]
* 0.0 HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level mail
* domains are different
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* -0.0 RP_MATCHES_RCVD Envelope sender domain matches handover relay domain
* 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* 0.1 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
* 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
* valid
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=1.0 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,HTML_MESSAGE,
RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2,RP_MATCHES_RCVD,SPF_PASS autolearn=no
autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
X-Spam-Score: 1.0

To learn more about the terms used in the SpamAssassin report, please search
here: http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (adapted from 
draft-kucherawy-sender-auth-header-04.txt):
==========================================================

"pass"
the message passed the authentication test.

"fail"
the message failed the authentication test.

"softfail"
the message failed the authentication test, and the authentication
method has either an explicit or implicit policy which doesn't require
successful authentication of all messages from that domain.

"neutral"
the authentication method completed without errors, but was unable
to reach either a positive or a negative result about the message.

"temperror"
a temporary (recoverable) error occurred attempting to authenticate
the sender; either the process couldn't be completed locally, or
there was a temporary failure retrieving data required for the
authentication. A later retry may produce a more final result.

"permerror"
a permanent (unrecoverable) error occurred attempting to
authenticate the sender; either the process couldn't be completed
locally, or there was a permanent failure retrieving data required
for the authentication.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

From 0100015aef9be4a3-79335e7f-1214-481c-afe2-f1f3b01567ac-000000@amazonses.com Tue Mar 21 06:44:20 2017
Return-path: <0100015aef9be4a3-79335e7f-1214-481c-afe2-f1f3b01567ac-000000@amazonses.com>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on
localhost.localdomain
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Report: 
* -0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, no
* trust
* [54.240.8.16 listed in list.dnswl.org]
* 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -2.8 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2 RBL: Average reputation (+2)
* [54.240.8.16 listed in wl.mailspike.net]
* 0.0 HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level mail
* domains are different
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* -0.0 RP_MATCHES_RCVD Envelope sender domain matches handover relay domain
* 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* 0.1 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
* 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
* valid
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=1.0 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,HTML_MESSAGE,
RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2,RP_MATCHES_RCVD,SPF_PASS autolearn=no
autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
Envelope-to: ins-1o0neojk@isnotspam.com
Delivery-date: Tue, 21 Mar 2017 06:44:20 +0000
Received: from a8-16.smtp-out.amazonses.com ([54.240.8.16])
by localhost.localdomain with esmtp (Exim 4.84_2)
(envelope-from <0100015aef9be4a3-79335e7f-1214-481c-afe2-f1f3b01567ac-000000@amazonses.com>)
id 1cqDWm-0006Ll-2u
for ins-1o0neojk@isnotspam.com; Tue, 21 Mar 2017 06:44:20 +0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
s=2v7oaw3uek2ggiio5bsiibhbwimyo5tw; d=marketing.rupyacard.com;
t=1490078655;
h=Content-Type:List-ID:List-Unsubscribe:From:To:Subject:Message-ID:Date:MIME-Version;
bh=7eUpQISn49ePw528mwOP8z+ISRswwkS7aTlun7aKhDk=;
b=AuuJp+JZ2xcxndHXFO/B2JFDDMyDvuvYb0ifWM3W0/JJIPOezjKf9541UM/KvzfK
+IEVbPw1jmbNf8FI0lPBwJqSh37jCOoTsIfBqBYz5peig1DevCZ/dB3dRO+V1QBn6Lc
ecX9SV5Q9b6aZzdcbJPLgwuJoQMQsLpxZVXv8qjg=
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
s=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono; d=amazonses.com; t=1490078655;
h=Content-Type:List-ID:List-Unsubscribe:From:To:Subject:Message-ID:Date:MIME-Version:Feedback-ID;
bh=7eUpQISn49ePw528mwOP8z+ISRswwkS7aTlun7aKhDk=;
b=if6NCxspqNzynTLrSnVftjbgkbr+n/BxNW9Ld/hEN5QF9Ym99m/AMRS/tGFjzxqT
NXNtBwyiLl9jXFTf4EkJT8f/BLHfFl2rIK17lRL4AjzTDmIAlCjpiUVkO9y+ffByydr
9u7We52BNed/DWgrnk0XMxEllo8xB9oeSUtmeKKE=
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="--_NmP-735122ddeafac769-Part_1"
X-FBL: SktI3Jpsg.HJJsVUTqe.BkD3oB0il
X-Msys-Api: {"campaign_id":"SktI3Jpsg.HJJsVUTqe.BkD3oB0il"}
X-SMTPAPI: {"unique_args":{"campaign_id":"SktI3Jpsg.HJJsVUTqe.BkD3oB0il"}}
X-Mailgun-Variables: {"campaign_id":"SktI3Jpsg.HJJsVUTqe.BkD3oB0il"}
List-ID: RupyaCard <HJJsVUTqe.emailer.rupyacard.com>
List-Unsubscribe: https://emailer.rupyacard.com/subscription/HJJsVUTqe/unsubscribe/BkD3oB0il?auto=yes
From: Rupya Card <newsletter@marketing.rupyacard.com>
To: ins-1o0neojk@isnotspam.com
Subject: Put your money to work with RupyaCard
Message-ID: <0100015aef9be4a3-79335e7f-1214-481c-afe2-f1f3b01567ac-000000@email.amazonses.com>
X-Mailer: Mailtrain Mailer (+https://mailtrain.org)
Date: Tue, 21 Mar 2017 06:44:15 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-SES-Outgoing: 2017.03.21-54.240.8.16
Feedback-ID: 1.us-east-1.0nEpnpYhLZSXLX1V0WLf4sSskZMvsCRsPVijMzoBDUs=:AmazonSES
X-DKIM-Status: invalid (pubkey_unavailable)
X-DKIM-Status: pass (amazonses.com)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to send a high volume of emails to be marked as spam, actually, one of the most important things are the ratio between people that clicked on "marked as spam", successful deliveries and bounces (especially hard bounces).

Have you validated the emails from your list before sending?

Depending on how you acquired the e-mails on your list, you may have sent your first e-mail batch to several spam traps, deactivated e-mails, and so on. Check you delivery report from MailGun.

There are 2 more things that may have contributed to your domain being marked as spam.

1. Using the word "money" in the subject line
2. Having too much image without a plain text version of your e-mail

At least this is what I saw from ISnotSPAM report.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately right after the first mail, gmail marked us as spam. 
>   ...Not sure why it says DKIM failing. 
>   Any other reasons why we got marked as spam?

There's a couple of possibilities.

1. Fix your DKIM issue. If any part of your mail record is invalid, then you cannot blame other mail servers for labeling your mail as spam. Every minute, servers pass incoming mail through a bunch of filters in order to try to give guests genuine mail from genuine people.
2. I'm gonna make my answer apply to all email servers here (including gmail)... It can be marked as spam if the same message is sent numerous of times in a very short time frame.

Your emails may also be marked as spam if the target email account has filters setup to move your emails to the spam folder.

3. If you're sending mail at a ridiculous speed to one domain, consider slowing down the rate at which you send mails. For example, consider sending one email an hour instead of one email a minute. Trying to access the same domain at a ridiculous speed (especially if many computers do it) is a cause for DoS (denial of service) attack.

Consider opening up multiple email accounts but through different servers. Maybe use a gmail one, a yahoo one, msn/hotmail or whatever else is out there for email, and test your mail in all of them.

Also, make your emails look genuine and valid. Use text so that people who don't understand your language can run the text through a converter. Use titles that describe the mail and use email addresses that describe a member of a company. Try to avoid extensive marketing words.

Example email addresses you might want to use are:

```
support@domain.com
help@domain.com
information@domain.com
```

Bad email addresses:

```
buynowfor599@domain.com
limitedtimeoffer@domain.com
globalmarketing@domain.com
freemoney@domain.com
```

And for titles, maybe use one of these:

```
Technical Support
Your request for _____ is being _____
Regarding your recent ________
```

These are bad titles:

Hurry! Limited time offer. Claim now!
   come get your $1,000,000 
   Read this for a free deposit of $1M
   Buy one get one free

(of course, blank means fill in the blank)

The reason why I list bad and good email titles and addresses is because you want to ensure you avoid extensive marketing buzz and make your emails legitimate. People do not like to be tricked into scams.

Now if you really want to test things, here's what I recommend.

For the mailer email, use the address: test@domain.com, and the title "this is a test", and make the body of the email "this is a test".

Send that email to new accounts you set up on different domains and if all emails went through then you need to work on your email content.

Comment: The issue is, what's wrong in my DKIM? Every tool out there except for isnotspam syas dkim is correct!